# Woher kommt der Ausdruck "Knast haben"?

Tags: etymology

Woher kommt der  Ausdruck ***Knast** haben*?

Ich denke, der Ausbreitungsraum und die Bedeutung sind relativ unumstritten: In den neuen Bundesländern wird der Ausdruck umgangssprachlich synonym zu *Hunger haben* gebraucht.

> Ich hab so'n Knast! Was gibs zum Mittag?

Allerdings habe ich keine wirklich gute Erklärung oder Belege zur Wortherkunft gefunden. 
Im Netz steht oft, dass es was mit Gefängnis zu tun hätte. Das kommt mir doch etwas weit hergeholt vor.

Meine beste Idee wäre eine Umschreibung des Magengrummelns: *knas* dann für Knacken. (wie heute noch im Dänischen zu finden)

**EDIT** Warum die Herleitung von Gefängnis mir unwahrscheinlich erscheint:

Zum einen finde ich es fraglich, dass eine Gefängnisreferenz sich im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch derart verbreitet hat. Es fehlt doch der Bezug zum alltäglichen Leben, damit auch jeder etwas mit dem Ausspruch anfangen kann. Ein Gegenbeweis wäre m.e. der Beleg, dass das Aufkommen des Ausspruchs mit einer Zeit von staatlicher Repression/Massenverhaftungen korreliert. (Der einzig vergleichbare Gefängnisausdruck, der mir einfällt, ist das *Seife aufheben* und das hat sich als Referenz in jüngster Zeit m.E. nur durch moderne Medien (Serien) so verbreitet.)

Auch drückt das Verb *haben*, ja Besitz aus. Sicher kann dieser Ausspruch dann durch Weglassen verkürzt worden sein, doch zum einen fällt mir da kein vergleichbares Beispiel mit *haben* ein und zum zweiten müssten sich dann ja Ursprungs- oder Übergangsformen finden lassen. z.B. *ich habs **wie im** Knast*

Subjektiv (als jemand der den Ausdruck verwendet) macht es auch vom Sprachgefühl keinen Sinn. Ich benutze *Knast* haben für meinen aktuellen Zustand. Während eine Bedeutung à la *ich habe es wie im Gefängnis* ja doch eher langfristig ist.

Comment: "Das kommt mir doch etwas weit hergeholt vor." Warum? Zumindest in früheren Zeiten wurde man im Gefängnis (oder als Soldat im Arrest) nicht besonders gut verpflegt. Außerdem, wenn der Ernährer im Gefängnis saß, hatte die Familie i.d.R. Hunger zu leiden.

Comment: Danke @Roland habe meine Frage erweitert

Comment: Hilft hier nicht wirklich weiter, aber etwas Wortherkunftskunde schadet ja auch nicht: Duden Universalwörterbuch sagt zu *Knast*: "vgl. jiddisch knas, hebräisch gĕnạs = Geldstrafe]." - Weiter noch *Knaster*: "ursprünglich = edler, würziger Tabak, der in »Rohrkörben« gehandelt wird, zu niederländisch knaster < spanisch canasto < griechisch kánastron = Korb]." - Dürfte man vermuten, dass *knast haben* vielleicht eher von *kanastron haben* ("einen leeren Korb haben") kommt?

Comment: Mundmische hat einen Eintrag, aber leider ohne weitere Infos: https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/14140-Knast.

Comment: Siehe https://www.deutschlandfunkkultur.de/durch-den-wind-sein.1306.de.html?dram:article_id=193538

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rolf-Bernhard Essig hat sich im Deutschlandradio / Deutschlandfunk Kultur [ebenfalls mit der Frage beschäftigt](https://www.deutschlandfunkkultur.de/durch-den-wind-sein.1306.de.html?dram:article_id=193538) und führt die Herkunft auf das Wort "[knastern](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK08586#XGK08586)" zurück. Er schrieb:

> Das Wort „Knast“ in Zusammenhang mit Hunger könnte man auf den [...] Ausdruck „Knust“ zurückführen, also das Endstück eines Brotlaibs, **doch geht es auf den lautmalerischen Ausdruck „knastern“ zurück**, der einerseits das Verbrennungsgeräusch bestimmter harzreicher Holzarten bezeichnet, andererseits [...] das Knabbern an Nüssen [...]. Die Verbindung zum Essen lag also nahe, doch muss man noch bedenken, dass ein „Knast“ ein knorriges Holzstück und davon abgeleitet ein grober Kerl sein konnte. Dessen brummige, abweisende Laute nannte man ebenfalls „kanstern“. Wenn jemand also „Knast“ hatte, war er ursprünglich brummig, ungehalten. Das ist einerseits aber natürlicherweise der Fall, wenn man Hunger hat, andererseits führt der Hunger dazu, dass der Magen knurrt, was wiederum auf die Geräuschanteile der Knast-Wortfamilie hindeutet.

Die Verbindung zum ursprünlich jiddischen Ausdruck knas verneint er.

> Mit dem Knast, also dem Gefängnis, wo man ja auch knapp gehalten wurde und also Hunger haben konnte, hat das nichts zu tun, den der kommt vom jiddischen „knas“, was „Geldstrafe“ bedeutet.

Comment: "*Dessen brummige, abweisende Laute nannte man ebenfalls „kanstern“.*" - ist das ein Buchstabendreher und sollte eigentlich *knastern* heißen?

Comment: Der Ausdruck scheint nur in den östlichen Teilen Deutschlands bekannt zu sein.

Answer (score 4):

Im norddeutschen Raum bedeutet(e) *Knast* umgangssprachlich auch *Buckel*. Extremer Hunger hat negative Folgen, u.a. Magenschmerzen. Da die meisten Menschen sich bei Magenschmerzen eher krümmen als ausstrecken, was medizinisch gesehen ratsam wäre, krümmen sie den Rücken, bekommen also plus/minus einen Buckel. Eine Paraphrase für "Mann, hab' ich ein' Knast!" könnte also sein: "Ich bin schon ganz krumm vor lauter Hunger."

Answer (score 2):

### Ast / Knast

Allgemein bekannt ist der *Ast* im Zusammenhang mit Hungern überwiegend nur als Teil des Worts **[Hungerast](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hungerast)**, mit dem ein akuter Glukosemangel bei Ausdauersportlen bezeichnet wird (auch bekannt als *[Mann mit dem Hammer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann_mit_dem_Hammer)*).

[image: Hungerast im Marathon]
<sup>[Marathonsportler](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/Boston_marathon_mile_25_helper_050418.jpg/276px-Boston_marathon_mile_25_helper_050418.jpg) in der Erschöpfung, rechts</sup>

Das Wort *Ast* soll sich angeblich aus der, wie im Bild oben zu sehen, gekrümmten Haltung herleiten.

Ein ganz ähnlicher Bezug könnte man auch mit dem niederdeutschen Wort [Knast](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK08574#XGK08574) (knorriger oder auch dürrer Ast) bestehen.

Answer (score 0):

Falls Knast von Knast haben wirklich  auf Knust zurückgeht, müßte der Vokalwandel, wenn nicht begründet, so doch mindestens belegt werden. Gibt es denn die Wendung "Knust haben", oder was Ähnliches?

Answer (score -1):

Zuerst: Ich kenne den Ausdruck für "Hunger" nicht. In meiner Gegend ist er nicht verbreitet.

Der Online-Duden kennt zwei Substantive unter *Knast*, die er für nicht miteinander verwandt hält - Einmal einen Ausdruck für das Gefängnis, der aus der Gaunersprache stammt und wohl mit deiner Frage nichts zu tun hat, zum Anderen einen regionalen Ausdruck, der laut Duden

> Knorren, Aststück, Astansatz

oder

> dickes Stück Brot

bedeutet. Die erste Bedeutung dürfte hier irrelevant sein, die zweite schon eher - "Lust auf ein Stück Brot" dürfte hier die Bedeutung sein.

Ein paar weitere interessante Hinweise hat der Duden unter *Herkunft* noch für uns:

> verwandt mit *Knust*

was wiederum der Endstück eines Brotlaibs ist und mit solchen Wörtern wie *verknusen* (futtern, essen) verwandt ist. Der Kreis zum Essen ist somit geschlossen.

Das wiederum kennt man auch im Südwesten Deutschlands, dort ist der *Knaus* ein Brot-Endstück oder ein Knorren/Ast.

Comment: Der OP hat schon recht, wenn er sagt, dass der Ausdruck vor allem in den östlichen Bundensländern vorkommt. Daher kenne ich ihn auch. Em Schwobaland sait ma dees it. Interessant finde ich aber, dass der Ausdreck noch nicht in die größeren Wörterbücher geschafft hat.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann "dass der Ausdreck noch nicht in die größeren Wörterbücher geschafft hat" - vielleicht, weil Dreck dort generell nichts verloren hat? (SCNR)

Comment: Knast haben als Hunger haben ist aber das ungefähre Gegenteil von Brot haben. Das macht keinen Sinn. Lust auf Knast haben hat man auch nicht gehört. Wieso könnte die Lust weggefallen sein, wenn sich dadurch der Sinn verkehrt? Kennst Du das von anderen Redewendungen?